# Integration of OpenSocial API into Moodle

Tags: api, moodle, opensocial, apache-shindig

I want to add  a Open social gadget into moodle via apache shindig  but the problem i  don't know how integrate this server into moodle to view the social information of student

Answer (score 0):

There's a module and a block for OpenSocial written by the same author. Looks like they are for Moodle 2.1 though - although there is a note in the readme about updating the code for Moodle 2.2 - there were significant changes to Moodle between 2.1 and 2.2 - so it should work for the latest versions of Moodle in theory

https://github.com/vohtaski/shindig-moodle-mod

https://github.com/vohtaski/shindig-moodle-block

Comment: Thank you for your help,i tried this tutorial  but i don't  know  how  configure  exactly the apache shindig   and how integrate into moodle